# Impossible to create an environment with a specific game (gym retro)

Tags: python, python-3.x, openai-gym

I'm trying to create a game environement in pyhton 3.6.8 using gym-retro.
It's a stable game name **SpaceInvaders-Atari2600** located in "..retro\data\stable\"

The basic command is :

```
env = retro.make(game='SpaceInvaders-Atari2600')
```

but that isn't working for me and i got the error :

*raise FileNotFoundError('Game not found: %s. Did you make sure to import the ROM?' % game)
FileNotFoundError: Game not found: SpaceInvaders-Atari2600. Did you make sure to import the ROM?*

**But** the problem is that the ROM is here, in the folder SpaceInvaders-Atari2600 there is a file named *"rom.sha"*

```py
import gym
import retro    

#Environment creation
env = retro.make(game='SpaceInvaders-Atari2600');
# don't work for me ...

# when i try this : 

for game in retro.data.list_games():
   print(game)

# I see the game SpaceInvaders-Atari2600
```

I'm desperated please if someone got an idea on how to create this environement...

**I'm totally new on python i never used it before this week, i have to use this language to test Q-learning training for a neural network so i can do stupid mistakes with syntaxe**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found the solutiuon, the ROM file i downloaded before wasn't valid that's all

If someone is following the same tuto as me, just to help him a valid rom is findable at this adresse :

https://www.gametronik.com/site/fiche/atari_2600/Space%2520Invaders/

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
wget http://www.atarimania.com/roms/Roms.rar && unrar x Roms.rar 
mkdir <new_dir>
unzip Roms/ROMS.zip -d <new_dir>
pip install gym-retro
python3 -m retro.import <new_dir>/ROMS/
```